# Mongoose: Odd behaviour with socketTimeoutMS in connection options

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to define custom timeout values when first establishing a connection with mongoose.connect(), but am seeing some strange results:

If I use basic options (without any timeouts specified), then everything works fine:

```
options = { server:{  auto_reconnect: true,  } }
```

However, if I try to specify `socketTimeoutMS` (e.g. 5000ms), then the connection repeatedly times out.

```
options = {
      server:{
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions:{
                connectTimeoutMS    : 30000,        
                socketTimeoutMS     : 5000,         
                keepAlive           : 1
            }
      }
}
```

However, despite the `[Error: connection to xxx timed out]` errors that I get, the application still works!

**Can anyone explain this behaviour?**

Other info:

- Mongoose v3.8.12 (Native driver 1.4.5)
- MongoDb Server v2.4.5
- Connecting to server on localhost (Windows 7 64bit)

Comment: you set the timeout to 5 seconds and you're asking why your connections are now timing out?   because you set the timeout too low.  isn't it what you wanted? or is your question about something else?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - 5 seconds is just an arbitrary value.   If I set it to 30, then it times out after 30 seconds.  There appears to be no value that is 'long enough'.  Perhaps I don't fully understand the purpose of socketTimeoutMS.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - We have been having problems with clients hanging indefinitely.  It seems that mongodb has extremely long/infinite default timeout values.  I wanted to specify shorter timeouts, so that we can handle the error situation rather than just hang.

Comment: cursors time out after 10 minutes.  But why are you trying to make connections time out?  There is overhead in reopening a connection - the whole point is to *reuse* connections (hence connection pooling).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes, I'm aware that there is overhead in re-establishing a connection (The values in listed are not the ones we are using in production btw), but setting this has helped out a lot with a number of issues we were having.  It seems as though from time to time a connection would become inactive somehow, and all requests to it just hang.  This has solved that problem, but I'm still hoping someone can explain the behaviour with `socketTimeoutMS` we are seeing.

Comment: Still not clear to me what there is to explain - you are setting auto_reconnect true, the connection is timing out, the driver is reconnecting - it appears to me that everything is behaving as expected (except maybe these "hung" connections you get but without more details it's hard to say what's going on there).

Comment: @asya Yes, connectTimeOut and Autoreconnect are behaving as I would expect. Re the hanging - I think getting into the details of this here would introduce too many issues into this question.  I suppose my question really boils down now to: What is the purpose of socketTimeoutMS?