# Mongoose not closing connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to connect to my MongoDB server on production.

```
  mongo   : {
    uri    : process.env.MONGO_URL,
    options: {
      user   : process.env.MONGO_USER,
      pass   : process.env.MONGO_PASS,
      server : {
        socketOptions: {
          keepAlive       : 1,
          socketTimeoutMS : 300000,
          connectTimeoutMS: 300000
        }
      },
      replset: {
        rs_name      : process.env.MONGO_RS_NAME || "set-name",
        socketOptions: {
          keepAlive       : 1,
          socketTimeoutMS : 300000,
          connectTimeoutMS: 300000
        },
        readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred',
        poolSize: 50
      }
    }

  }
```

I've set tcp_keepalive_time to 120:

`echo 120 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time`

The problem is the connections keep opening to the server but never closing.

1. Why are connections keep opening to the server?
2. Why are connections not being closed?

Comment: If you don't close them manually, they are kept open for `socketTimeoutMS`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030990/mongoose-odd-behaviour-with-sockettimeoutms-in-connection-options Btw: it is not unusual to have hundreds of connections open.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm not talking about hundreds... It's getting to around 30K connections and I'm expecting no more than ~900 (pool of 50 for 18 processes). I can't manually close a connection b/c I don't even know what's happening inside mongoose. Sometimes I'm getting a 'reconnect' event but sometime I don't. Not sure why.

Comment: Have a look at your config. Your connections persist for at least 300000ms (or 5 minutes), no matter what. Also, the tcp keep alive setting might interfere here. What I would do is to first disable tcp keep alive (which mongoose should manage on its own) and reduce the timeout values. (you don't really want to wait for 5 minutes for a connection, anyway, do you). From there: Free the Sherlock inside you! ;)

Comment: My Sherlock is fully active :) The problem now is that when I lowered socketTimeout to 30000ms I get sockets opening and hanging even faster. I also disabled `keepAlive` but still sockets are piling up rapidly. I'm using `sudo lsof -i :9999 | grep -i established | wc -l` to count them.